# SAS server: How to get machine name of client machine?

Tags: sas

I am running SAS Enterprise Guide on my PC to connect to a SAS instance on a server that is located within our network.

I am writing a SAS program that will run on the server which will use ODS to write an HTML file to a certain sub-folder in my PC. I can do that today using UNC-style pathnames (e.g. \\my_machine_name\C$\documents\results.html) as long as I hardcode the name of the client machine (i.e. "my_machine_name" in my example above). This example assumes that I have a folder called "C:\documents" in my PC)

Can SAS running on the SAS server identify the calling client machine (i.e. my PC) and get its network name dynamically? If that is possible, I can avoid the hard-coding of my UNC style pathname mentioned above.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usually you can find stuff like this by running

```
%put _ALL_;
```

I think `&_CLIENTMACHINE` is the one that would be helpful to you.